# How to insert images into image array in visual studio?

Tags: c#, arrays

The problem is I'm creating an image array inside the class. Inside the constructor of the class I'm inserting image elements into the array:

```
  public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
  {
     Image[] imgs;

     public MainPage()
     {
      imgs={img1, img2, img3, img4, img5, img6, img7, img8, img9, img10, img11, img12, img13, img14}  
     }
  }
```

These img1, img2, ... are the names of image elements in xaml code. Why is it showing errors?

Comment: What error? What xaml code?

Comment: can you help me with the syntax

Comment: `imgs = new Image[]{img1,img2,img3}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

is this all you need...?

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
   Image[] imgs;
   public MainPage()
   {
      imgs = new Image[] { img1, img2, img3, img4, img5, img6, img7, img8, img9, img10, img11, img12, img13, img14};
   }
 }
```

Take a look at [Object Initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx) and probably [Arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: yaa thanks but can you explain the way it is working i mean syntax

Answer (score 2):

Theres a `new` statement missing, and a semi-colon as well.

```
imgs= new[] { img1, img2, img3, img4, img5, img6, img7, img8, img9, img10, img11, img12, img13, img14};
```